# Getting memory address of particular bytes in radare2

Tags: radare2

in pwnlib there is a possibility to search for particular bytes, e.g. as follows for 0x66 byte:

```
print(next(p.elf.search(b'f')))
```

which in turn results in the following output:

```
4195268
```

Having this value it is possible to examine it as an address in radare2:

```
pd 1 @ 4195268

        0x004003c4      666c           insb byte [rdi], dx
```

And it refers properly to a sequence of bytes containing desired 'f' (0x66).
However, this is neither a physical address nor a virtual one:

```
[0x00400520]> ?v 4195268
        0x4003c4
[0x00400520]> ?p 4195268
        0x000003c4
```

And I couldn't get it from radare2 directly. Instead, searching for bytes in r2 results in reference to virtual address, not to the value returned by ELF class from pwntools.

```
[0x00400520]> /x 66

0x004003c4 hit10_0 66
```

So, what is it actually an address of? And how I can get the same value returned by pwntools in radare2?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

working the whole time with hex values only makes one stupid.

```
0x4003C4 -> 4195268 (dec)
```

In radare2 you may access memory given in different numeral systems